# Using Elements in the Url in dropdown

Tags: java, angular, url, dropdown

Here I have a task in which I have been given 4 url links in which details of student and its opted course is given.Now I wan't to create a dropdown in which the name of the student appears and when I select the name its corresponding details from the remaing url appears.
In Component.ts

```
urlNames = 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/1g7sq4';
urlDetails = 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/16r07g';
urlNumbers = 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/1c3wng';
urlArray = 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/18py7w';

strData:String='';
Name:string[]=[];

constructor(private netService:NetService){}

getData(){
  this.netService.getData(this.urlNumbers)
    .subscribe(resp => {
    this.strData =JSON.stringify(resp);
})
}
```

In component.html

```
 <div class="container">
   <label>Select:</label>
   <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="sname">
     <option value=null>Select the Option ...</option>
     <option>https://api.myjson.com/bins/1g7sq4 </option>
   </select>
   <button class="btn-primary" (click)="getData()">Get Data</button>
   {{strData}}
 </div>
```

Comment: Could you post what you have done so far?

Comment: @DarshanMehta i edited the Question have a look

Answer (score 0):

You can try do it in automatic way using changeEvent of select element. In my solution I deleted button, so start downloading when you select option. And important make unsubscribe using first() operator in observer.

component.ts:

```
const options = [{
    value: null,
    key: 'Select the Option ...'
},{
    value: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/1g7sq4',
    key: 'Names'
}, {
    value: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/16r07g',
    key: 'Details'
}, {
    value: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/1c3wng',
    key: 'Numbers'
}, {
    value: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/18py7w',
    key: 'Array'
}]

strData:String='';
Name:string[]=[];

constructor(private netService:NetService){}

getData(url: string): void {
    this.netService.getData(url).pipe(
        first(),
        tap(res => (this.strData =JSON.stringify(resp)))
    ).subscribe()
}
```

view.html

```
<div class="container">
  <label>Select:</label>
  <select class="form-control" #select (change)="getData(select.value)">
    <option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option.value">{{option.key}}</option>
  </select>
  {{strData}}
</div>
```